# How to call a different constructor based on variable value in Java

Tags: java

Its a simple question really.

```
class salad
class chef_salad extends salad
class ceasar_salad extends salad
```

So I have a variable `type` and I want to create the appropriate object based on type.

Apparently I can do

```
if(type.equals("chef"){ salad s = new chef_salad(); }
```

I suppose I can even make that a static method that returns a `salad` object, but is this really the best approach or there is a better way to do it through constructors?

ps. fictional example

Comment: just a side note, if you don't want people who will read/maintain your java code to say bad things, stick to java code conventions :) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
public static Salad createSaladInstance(String type)
{
    if(type.equals("Salad")) return new Salad();
    else if(type.equals("ChefSalad")) return new ChefSalad();
    // ...
}

// ...

Salad s = createSaladInstance(type);
```

Comment: If this is 'legit' then thats just fine! However @Vikdor Factory Pattern may be more appropriate for more complex cases, and a better practice in overall. +1 at both.

Answer (score 11):

You are talking about [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) where you want to hide the logic behind instantiating an object of a given type in an inheritance hierarchy, based on the inputs.

```
public class SaladFactory
{
    public Salad getSalad(type) {
        if ("chef".equals(type) {
            return new ChefSalad();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a design pattern for this! So the factory does just that then? Should I also make it static or there's a good reason to not do so?

Comment: +1: But it's specifically the Factory Method pattern.  There are other factory patterns...

Comment: Right @DonRoby, I too mean factory method.

Comment: @Andreas, I would make it a member function as mostly these factories are dependencies either injected or located in an enterprise application.

Comment: So I should go with what @Eng.Fouad suggested?

Comment: @Andreas, Where would you put such static method? at least not in any of the salad classes as it wouldn't fit there. You need to have a separate class to house this and it would better be a member function.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Factory Design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

```
public interface SaladFactory
   {
   public Salad createSalad();
   public String getName();
   }

for(SaladFactory factory:factories)
{
if(factory.getName().equals("caesar")) return facory.createSalad();
}
```